# How to use Secure Desktop for KeePassXC database master password

Tags: keepass, keepassxc

I don't know how to make sure that the database's master password is prompted through the ***Secure Desktop***, in a similar way to [KeePass 2 functionality](https://keepass.info/help/kb/sec_desk.html).

I feel like this should be an automatic behavior that's why I'm asking here.

**Edit**: initially i was wrongly asking about UAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secure Desktop is not present at the moment in KeePassXC, [the request can be found here](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/3460).
Please do support it.

NB: After the nice reply from Mokubai (related to my poor choice of words) I could find the solution
NB2: [nice explanation on the nature of the secure desktop feature in KeePass 2](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/how-does-the-windows-secure-desktop-mode-work/3762#3762)

Comment: I've deleted my answer so no need to mention, it was based on a misunderstanding . I was aware that UAC prompts happen *on* a secure desktop but didn't catch that you meant the program itself appearing in that area *instead* of the UAC prompt. This does sound like a nice extra layer of security that could be useful if you have people remote desktoping in to your machine but want to retain password security. Nice.

Comment: If it's not a problem I would like to keep the mention, also thanks for clearing my question with your answer! It is indeed an interesting little bit of security. In my case is also valid when I type and another app take focus after loading. With keepass2 and secure desktop it was never happening.

Comment: That is a good point, it could mean the difference between typing your password into the window you really want and a chat application suddenly popping up and you broadcasting it to a group accidentally. I don't have a problem with the mention, but future visitors may not be able to see my answer or may miss the edit history and wonder what was going on. Just something for the future...